# Slow Complex Builds & Hudson vs. Electric Cloud

Tags: build, hudson, distributed

Is hudson the right tool for complex C++ builds?

I have a C++ build that takes about 4 hours.  Compile and packaging take about 1/2 the time and testing consumes the other half.  Presently, we are using a home grown system but there's some move to go to hudson since we use it for all of our java builds.

My problem is that continuous integration isn't very...continuous at 4 hour intervals.  I want a tool that's going to let me parallelize the build in an understandable way.

Hudson's been great for small builds or java builds where I'm sitting at the top of a large maven project, but I don't think it will scale well for complex c++ builds.

What have your experiences been?

Comment: does it take 4 hours even for a simple incremental build, or is that the clean build time?  if it's the latter, can you do incremental builds instead?

Comment: Is there supposed to be something relating to Electric Cloud in the question? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems like you have a few questions here:

1. **Should I use a CI server to manage my C++ build?**  The answer to this is unequivocally YES.  Your homegrown system may be adequate, but it's not standard, extending it is probably difficult, and maintaining it is a distraction from the work you're actually paid to do.
2. **Is Hudson the right choice for my project?**  It will probably get the job done, and it has the advantage of being in deployment at your site already.  However, you specifically mention that you want a tool that supports parallelization well, and I don't think that Hudson really fits the bill.  The problem is that Hudson was not designed with parallelism in mind.  See, the representation of a build process in Hudson is a "job", which is just a series of steps executed in sequence -- checkout, compile, test, package, etc.  There's no way to get those steps to run in parallel.  Now, you can get around this by modeling your process with multiple jobs.  Each job is completely independent, so of course they could be run in parallel; you can use something like the [Locks and Latches plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Locks+and+Latches+plugin) to coordinate the jobs, but the whole process is more complicated than it ought to be, and kind of clumsy -- instead of a single job representing a single run of the build process, you have several unconnected jobs, at best tied together via naming convention.
3. **Can Electric Cloud help?**  Again, an unequivocal YES.  Electric Cloud offers ElectricCommander, a CI server with parallel support built-in from inception.  As with Hudson, a job is used to represent a build process, but the steps within a job can easily be run in parallel (just check the "parallel" box on those steps), so you don't have to resort to add-ons and kludges:  one run build process is one job, with as many parallel steps as you like.
4. **Will the right CI server put "continuous" back into my integration?**  A CI server will only get you so far.  The thing is, a CI server can provide you coarse-grained parallelism -- so with a little work, you can set it up to run packaging in parallel with tests, for example.  With a little more work, you can probably split your test phase into a few independent pieces that can be run in parallel.
     You didn't give many details, but let's assume that your build is 90 minutes of compile, 30 minutes of packaging, and 2 hours of tests that can be broken down into four 30 minute pieces.  Suppose further that you can do packaging and testing simultaneously.  That would bring your 4 hour process down to 2 hours total.  At this point the "long pole" in your process is the compile phase, and although you might be able to break that up by hand into pieces that can be run in parallel by your CI server, the truth is that the CI server is just not the right tool for that job.
     A better option is to use a build tool that can give you automatic fine-grained parallelism within the compile phase.  For example, if you're using gmake already, you can try `gmake -j 8` to run 8 compiles at once.  If your makefiles are clean and your dependencies are all correct, and you have a beefy build server, this could give you a pretty good performance boost.  You could also use ElectricAccelerator, another product from Electric Cloud, that was specifically designed to accelerate this portion of the build process, even for builds that can't safely use `gmake -j` due to incorrect or incomplete depedencies.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not split the build into multiple parts whatsoever?

You do mention that the job has several distinct parts.  The general guidance with Hudson is to do the build part in one job, testing in another, packaging in another, and so on.

You can compile the code in Job A and archive the output, then tell Job B to [copy these artifacts](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) from Job A and run the tests on them.  Meanwhile, another Job A can be kicked-off, due to further commits to the source repository..

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like the problem is with your build process (make files?, msbuild?) and not Hudson.  Hudson is simply going to execute the build process the same way a user would from a command-line.  Is it possible to optimize your build process?

Even if a 4 hour build process is unavoidable, Hudson can help because you can attach an unlimited number of slave machines which can all be running multiple builds in parallel, given adequate hardware horsepower.